# Dynamic key names from generic/object type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types, type-hinting

I'm using react-hook-form [package](https://react-hook-form.com/), which is neat.

One of the things you can do is watch changes on input fields by calling `useForm()` and using one of the events returned named `watch` like so:

```
const methods = useForm()

console.log('test watch', methods.watch("myrandominpuitname"))
```

which works great, however, if I would like to have autocomplete available on that `watch` method I have to pass some arguments to the `useForm` hook like so:

```
const methods = useForm<{
    'myrandominpuitname': string,
}>()

console.log('test watch', methods.watch("myrandominpuitname"))
```

That will provide me with autocomplete when trying to call the `methods.watch("...")`

My question is, is it possible to generate an object from a nested dataset and use that as the type for the `useForm`?

Sample Looped Dataset:

```
function useFormInputs(arrDataset: any[]) {
    let oInputs = {};
    arrDataset.map(dataset => {
        oInputs = Object.assign(oInputs, {[dataset.oField.oProps.name]: ''});
    });

    return useForm<typeof oInputs>();
}
```

Sample Object Result:

```
let test = {
    'myrandominpuitname1': '',
    'myrandominpuitname2': '',
    'myrandominpuitname3': '',
}
```

Is it possible to make that object into a type looking like this:

```
type myInputs = {
    'myrandominpuitname1': string,
    'myrandominpuitname2': string,
    'myrandominpuitname3': string,
};
```

I would like to generate it automatically,I have tried stuff like

```
type TestType<T> = {
    [index in T as string]: string;
};
```

The above sample with not recognize the unique names and will not provide me with autocomplete.

Does anyone know how to do this? My feeling is that it is prob very easy for someone who is experienced with Typescript. :)

Comment: Just use `typeof test `

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine Hey Captain, i have updated the question, I am having a nested dataset which holds the names, from there I'm building an object which looks like the sanoke ibhect result, if I just pass that as typeof it does not recognize my types

Comment: please be aware that typescript is about static typing , hence no autocomplete for data from database